# Add arrow to custom horizontal scrollbar Angular/HTML

Tags: html, css, angular, chart.js, scrollbar

I styled a horizontal Scrollbar  for my chartjs graph and tried to add arrows using material icons: `<mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_left</mat-icon>` but I can't seem to get it to align next to the left and right of the scrollbar. What is the simplest way to do this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the scrollbar and the chart is one same container than I guess you can try to wrap the chart and the arrows in one overall `div`, add to this `div` style `position: relative` and to each arrow `position: absolute; bottom: 0; right/left: 0;` You can also add `z-index: 1` to arrows to avoid overlapping.

Comment: The only issue is when you resize the screen the arrow gets misplaced